# Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseRestorePoints fails with authorisation error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am trying to use `Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseRestorePoints` and `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseRestorePoint` for managing Azure Datwarehouse restore points and restore process using Powershell. I am getting authorisation error when I call this command. I have contributor privileges at subscription and sql server level.

What I noticed that subscription id in the https request for API call is different from my selected subscription.
How can I force these commands to use my active subscription or can I pass subscription when I call this command.

**Error details**

```
Body:
   {
    "error": 
    "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
    "message": "The client 'xxxxxxx' with object id 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/restorePoints/read' over scope 
'/subscriptions/Subscription B/resourceGroups/DataWarehouse-SIT-rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/servername/databases/DataWarehouse'."
  }
}
```

**Full Code**

```
$subscription = "Subscription A"
Login-AzureRmAccount -Subscription $subscription
Get-AzureRmSubscription
Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription $subscription

$resourceGroup = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName
$server = Get-AzureRmSqlServer -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $serverName
$database = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ServerName $server.ServerName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -DatabaseName $databaseName
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseRestorePoint -RestorePointLabel $restorePointName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $server.ServerName -DatabaseName $database.DatabaseName
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved after upgrading AzureRM module. Issue exists in module version 5.7.0 but it is resolved in version 6.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself states that your account don't have READ permission to your restorepoints(Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/restorePoints/read). Can you verify your permissions or try with another account?

Comment: My account does have Contributor access and I am able to perform same operation using portal. What I noticed is that the API call generated by command uses different subscription to that of I have selected.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether do you have enough permission in your Subscription IAM

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal

1. Subscription IAM Policy

[image]

2. Add your Email

[image]

3. Add your Role(s)

[image]

**P.S: You need to contact your Subscription Owner in order to perform the above steps.**

Comment: Thanks for detailed instructions, my account does have Contributor access and I am able to perform same operation using portal. What I noticed is that the API call generated by command uses different subscription to that of I have selected.

Comment: @Shrek Please post your own answer then. Also, you can upvote the answers which you find helpful